# What can JavaScript do?

Tags: javascript

Hey, I am a newbie to JavaScript. I really don't know what it does.

- What can I do with JavaScript?
- What are the possibilities of JavaScript?
- What tools will I require to develop in JavaScript?
- Is there some plugin available in Eclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: One question at once, please.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is a programming language.

You can do anything with it that you can do with other programming languages.

As with other languages, you need a text editor and a compiler/interpreter in order to develop with it.

It is mostly used with websites to provide better interaction than HTML can do alone and most web browsers have a built in interpreter for javascript. For security reasons, javascript in the browser is limited (so it can't directly access the filesystem, for example).

See [this](http://www.chipchapin.com/WebTools/JavaScript/javascript-uiuc-resources.html) list of resources for further learning.

Comment: True. However, the most popular use for JavaScript is client-side JavaScript (JavaScript in browsers). All the browsers' implementation limits JavaScript's functionality or fails to provide access to functionality (cross-domain policies, no local file system interaction etc.)

Comment: Javascript can do low-level IRQ manipulation in a Windows app? (For instance)

Comment: @Tobiasopdenbrouw - if you have an interpreter/compiler for it, there is no reason why not. http://javascript.weblogsinc.com/2006/08/06/javascript-outside-of-the-browser/

Comment: I would say that JavaScript is a scripting language and not a programming language. Please see this link for explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968461/why-javascript-is-called-as-scripting-language

Comment: @Julian - are you saying that when you write a script, you are not programming?

Comment: @Oded By writing a script I wouldn't call that programming. When I write a script I prefer to say that I'm scripting.

Comment: The act is still that of programming. The what executes the "script" is an interpreter and not a compiler doesn't change the fact (and there are tools out there that will compile JavaScript to an executable). Don't conflate the runtime characteristics with the act of programming - you are still writing code that the computer will execute, @Julian.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a programming language used, in context of web sites, to implement behavior function to a page on client side. Using HTML and CSS only, with no Javascript, you can only show things in a pre-defined way. With Javascript, you can control the way things behave.

You can use whatever text editor you like to write Javascript code, and a web browser to run it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is well-suited for performing task within a web browser.It is primarily used to interact with users.
With JavaScript you can do:

- it can change HTML content, HTML styles, HTML attributes.
- it can detect what browser a person is using and customize the webpages to their browser.
- it can validate date.
- perform calculation in forms.
- validating form input.
- interact with multiple frames.